# Was my reputation change +5, +2, perhaps both, or some other combination?

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-history

Reputation dropdown says: +2 notification. Going into details, it also shows +5, +2 and +2 reputation all for the same "edit" being completed.

This certainly seems like a UX bug to me, because it's sending several unclear, mixed messages.

For starters, I thought I got +2 only (white text, green square). Then, I thought I got +5, or +7, or +9, depending on how the little green +N numbers are supposed to add up (green text).

What's really happening here? Can we improve it? Did I find an actual bug? :D

[image: Reputation dropdown says: +2 notification. Going into details, it also shows +5, +2 and +2 reputation all for the same "edit" being completed]

Answer (score 6):

+5 on Stack Overflow (under the Stack Overflow logo).

+2 on UX (under the UX logo).

Those are aggregates for the day, across all sites.

Under those, highlighted the *actual* change you have been notified about. Which is the +2 for UX.

I see no bug.

Comment: Aha! The "aggregates" row is what bothered me! Without something to clearly express that row's purpose as an handy aggretation, I had interpreted the row as "I got +5 points on StackOverflow for getting +2 points on UX". I say there's an issue in the UX - a lack of clarity upon the first glance of the aggregates row, causing confusion in the special case that there are exactly 2 sites being shown.